# CRM 2011 case escalation to team in other BU - old owner still needs access

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We have an issue where we need to separate access to cases depending on the customer's country, but some (most cases) gets assigned to a central help desk / R&D dept. before being send back to the originating team.

Currently all is in one BU, with teams for the different countries. Accounts and Contacts are owned by the country team, Cases are owned by team/user and activities are owned by the user who created it.

Right now we assign the case between different teams and persons - the question is if this is the correct approach? The issue is that while the case is owned by the central help desk or our R&D, the originating country teams users cannot see the case or the progress.

Is the correct approach to have the country team retain ownership on the case & the associated activities - and then use either a custom field or queues to decide who is to work on the case / resolve the activities?

So instead of using "Owner" as indicator for "responsible to solve", use "Owner" as "who can access this record"?

Or should i simply enable "share on reassign" option - will that not affect performance badly over time since most records would have 10+ sharing entries.

Once I have established the right way to do the things I'll create a program to set things right in terms of ownership - that is the trivial part, once I know the right flow.

Thank you in advance for your opinions / suggestions.

Br
Nicolai

Comment: You say that "we need to separate access to cases depending on the customer's country" - is this a matter of keeping these records secret, or simply one of convenience so that users only see the Cases that are relevant to them?

Comment: Hi AdamV - thank's. It's a matter of confidentiality - our management does not want to disclose all issues we have with all users.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to share between cases using "Share reassigned with original owner" is an overkill, does not share with entire country team (just the previous owner), and might cause serious performance issues down the road.

I think you should duplicate this behavior, however, for cases only in a custom plug-in, establish a routing table between teams / owners and add / revoke share access for these records when they meet sharing criterion.

Comment: Wow yeah, if I understand you correctly then on case reassign ensure it is shared with the country-team needed. And when it is re-assigned back to the country revoke that access? That's brilliant will preserve performance. I had not thought of it that way. I already have the routing table (http://www.pedroinnecco.com/projects/countryregion-dynamicscrm/ with a custom field to Teams). Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the cascading relationships between Account:Case and Contact:Case and make sure the Reparent behaviour is set to Cascade All or Active.

This should then mean that the owner of an Account will have access to any of that customer's Cases as if they own them (even though they don't). If the Account is owned by a Team, this is extended to the members of the Team.

Comment: That's the way we have it today except for Cases and Activities - the whole issue is that when you re-assign a case to central support then you can no longer see it. 

I think CRM did some implicit sharing earlier (until UR15 or something) because older cases can be seen by whole teams, newer cannot - no matter if they have been owned by the team earlier or not. There are no records shown in Sharing but I can find some in the SQL table that's invisible from CRM. So either there have been a bug or there is a bug now (sigh!) :D